# How to get all DataColumns of a DataTable to Lists

Tags: c#, list, linq, datatable, datacolumn

I want to get all DataColumns (of double type) of my DataTable in Lists and then create a Dictionary where the Key would be the header of the DataColumn and the Value would be the List with the data of the DataColumn. How can I achieve this with LINQ?

I tried the following lines without success:

```
// Create Dictionary
Dictionary<string, List<double>> DataDic = new Dictionary<string, List<double>>(); 

// Create List
List<double> DataList = new List<double>();

// For each DataColumn save it as a List of double
DataList = (from DataColumn dc in dt.Columns select new double()).ToList();

// Add KVP to DataDic
DataDic.Add(column.ColumnName, DataList);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is pretty straight forward:

```
// Create Dictionary
var DataDic = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                        .Where(dc => dc.DataType == typeof(double))
                        .ToDictionary(dc => dc.ColumnName,
                                      dc => dt.AsEnumerable()
                                              .Select(r => r.Field<double>(dc.ColumnName))
                                              .ToList()
                        );
```